# Sound card with Multiple Jacks

Tags: audio, sound-card, audio-output

If a laptop has multiple output sound jacks, like in the HP DV6 series, I am able to get output from the all the jacks (i.e the same output is received).

I would like to ask if I can get different sound outputs from applications on the sound jack of the sound card on a laptop (e.g If I can listen music on, while the movie is being played, the other sound jack output).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. I have seen cases where an application might allow you to select different outputs, but in general the output is controlled system-wide by the audio drivers or Windows audio manager.

Comment: Example of any such application that can be utilised to perform such task.

Comment: Ah - a quick check of Windows Media Player shows that it does indeed allow you to explicitly set which output to use, separate from the OS-level settings. I'm sure other media players can do the same. To see this go to Tools > Options > Devices > Speakers > select audio device

Answer (score 1):

Most likely these are going to be two duplicate outputs on a hardware level. As in, they are simply splitting the signal and amplifying it a little more than normal to keep good sound levels on both outputs. If they are two discrete outputs at the device level then proper drivers and compatible applications may be able to send two different outputs. But I'm pretty sure that's not the case.

Comment: This was my thought too, but I realized that after playing with my Dell (also having two analog outs), they are on separate channels and can be configured in software to even support 5.1 channel surround when used in combo with the microphone (a 3rd analog jack).

Comment: I had a DV1000, which was one of the early HP systems to have 2 outputs. It could not be configured the was your Dell was. The DV6 was only a short generation after the DV1000, so I assume it has a similar setup, though I could be very, very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this using ASIO4ALL audio driver: http://www.asio4all.com/